# Correct way of setting a BOOL property

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a BOOL property that I want to set in my class initializer.

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isEditMode; 

- (id)init
{
    . . . 
    [self setValue:NO forKey:isEditMode];
    return self;
}
```

The compiler gives me an "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion" warning. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Key-Value Coding method `setValue:forKey:` only accepts objects as arguments. To set a BOOL, you need to wrap the number in a value object with `[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`. But there's little reason to do that. Key-Value Coding is a roundabout way to accomplish this. Either do `self.isEditMode = NO` or just `isEditMode = NO`. The latter is preferable in an init method (because setters can run arbitrary code that might not be desirable before an object is fully set up).

But to elaborate on the first point: The reason Key-Value Coding works this way is because the type system can't represent an argument that's sometimes an object and at other times a primitive value. So KVC always deals with objects and just autoboxes primitive values as necessary. Similarly, if you do `[yourObject valueForKey:@"isEditMode"]`, you'll get back an NSNumber object wrapping the real value.

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax to set a property is just

```
self.isEditMode = NO;
```

If you want to use `-setValue:forKey:` you'd have to write it as

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:NO] forKey:@"isEditMode"];
```

However, there's absolutely no reason to do this in your situation.

That said, since you're in an `init` method, I would strongly recommend avoiding any property access whatsoever and instead using the ivar directly, as in

```
isEditMode = NO;
```

This avoids the possibility of an overridden setter being called (either in this class or a subclass) that makes the assumption that the object has already completed initialization. For this same reason you also want to avoid property access inside of `-dealloc`.

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign the value directly:

```
isEditMode = NO;
```

Comment: `setValue:forKey:` is a method of NSObject. It will be valid for any Cocoa object.

Comment: what is the problem with using KVC in setting the BOOL value? Is KVC meant for objects only?

Comment: If you're using KVC to set it, the key is a string. `isEditMode` is the actual boolean ivar in your class; what you want is `@"isEditMode"`, a string naming that ivar.

Comment: As well, the values in KVC are always objects, so you must box a `BOOL` value in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: Is there any reason someone would want to use KVC in the init method instead of setting the properties directly?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

```
self.isEditMode = NO;
```

---

If your code does indeed compile (I'm pretty new to Objective-C so I don't know) `setValue` probably takes a pointer to a string (`@"isEditMode"`, e.g.) and not some other type (`isEditMode`, e.g.).

Comment: A setter would work, but it's not necessary. The OP said he want to set the value in the class initializer and he hasn't redefined the setter in his property statement.