# Objective-c assigning Boolean property of class not working

Tags: objective-c, properties, boolean, setter, getter-setter

I have a subclass of an UIImageView with some boolean properties as follows: And I cannot set the isOccupied value to YES in my code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TargetView : UIImageView

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* letter;
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isMatched;
@property (assign) BOOL isOccupied;

-(instancetype) initWithLetter:(NSString*) letter andSideLength:(float)sideLength;

@end
```

Each of these TargetViews are stored in  `NSMutableArray* _targets;`

And when I execute the following

```
   for (TargetView* tv in _targets) {
        if (!tv.isOccupied) {
            tv.isOccupied = YES;
           //[tv setIsOccupied:YES]; <--- have also tried used this setter
            break;
        }
    }
```

The targetView is still evaluating as False the next time I run the code.  So I am not able to set the isOccupied value to TRUE, true or YES.

I initialise the targetView as follows, and all targetViews are initially set to isOccupied is false

```
-(instancetype)initWithLetter:(NSString *)letter andSideLength:(float)sideLength{
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blank.png"];
self = [super initWithImage:img];

if (self != nil) {
    self.isMatched = NO;
    self.isOccupied = NO;

    float scale = sideLength/img.size.width;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width*scale, img.size.width*scale);

    _letter = @"";
}
return self;
```

}

The code that is assigning the boolean value to the targetView is delegate method running in the controller and not within the targetView class itself.  Could this be causing the problem?  Or is it how I have set up my properties? I've tried assign, atomic, nonatomic, ......

EDIT**

I changed some to the code to use `**_isOccupied**` instead of `**self.isOccupied**` in the class initialisation.  and now it works.  Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864239/using-a-bool-property or  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482444/correct-way-of-setting-a-bool-property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting `self.isOccupied` during the initialization of `self`.

Self is not fully initialized yet and you are trying to use a property of it. Obviously the property is not initialized yet.

The property `self.isOccupied` is backed up by a local variable ("ivar") called _isOccupied. Every time you store something on `self.isOccupied`, iOS is storing the value on `_isOccupied`.

iOS will accept using that iVar directly because that is already initialized.

BTW, Apple suggests you to use the following syntax when you use "is" on a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter=isOccupied) BOOL occupied;
```

then you can use `image.occupied = YES` to set and `[image isOccupied];` to get.